# How can i detect one word with speech recognition in Python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I know how to detect speech with Python but this question is more specific:
How can I make Python listening for only one word and then returns True if Python could recognize the word.

I know, I could just let Python listen all the Time and then make something like that
Pseudocode:

```
while True:
    if stt.listen() == "keyword":
        return True
```

I have already made that and the program is hanging up after some minutes of always listening (See at the end). So I need a way to only listen for one specific word.

**What does "hang up" mean?** The program is not crashing but not responding. It isn't listening to my voice anymore and when I press `STRG + C` it does nothing.

I am searching for something like this:

```
while True:
    if stt.waitFor("keyword"):
        return True
```

Hope you understood, Best regards

Comment: The speech_recognition Package in Python 2.7. I excuse I forgot some technical details.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: Real-time or from a wav-file?

Comment: It's real-time processing with a microphone

Comment: @NoahFisher you can [edit] your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys, os
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *
import pyaudio

modeldir = "../../../model"
datadir = "../../../test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'forward')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e+20)


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream()

# Process audio chunk by chunk. On keyword detected perform action and restart search
decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
         decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
         break
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
        print ([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
        print ("Detected keyword, restarting search")
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```

For more details see http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Comment: Wow, Thank you, will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to install Pocketsphinx, Sphinxbase and the dependiencies. Could you help me?

Comment: Sure, please provide what did you try and what didn't work. `pip install pocketsphinx` should work.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `pip install pocketsphinx` but it says `swig.exe` is missing. I downloaded swig but now I don't know where to place the files. I also hope this will work on Linux too.

Comment: You can place swig.exe into current folder

Comment: Okay, I now went on my Raspberry Pi with Linux because I thought it would be easier to install everything. And the Raspberry Pi will also be the system I develop my program for. Everything went good after having some trouble with some other files. But now I don't know what to put into the `modeldir` and the `datadir`. I guess it's the Language-Model. Where can I get those files from? I would prefer German but English works too. Thanks a lot, you are rescueing me.

Comment: Modeldir is usually /usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model, the folder where you have en-us. Datadir is required for file recognition, it is not required for microphone decoding. For experiments with file you can use current folder as datadir. German model is available in downloads on our website.

Comment: I now downloaded the cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz and gave it into my "model/en-us/en-us". At the beginning it initialises very long and reads those files, but after some time, following error occurs (shortened):

ERROR: "dict.c": Failed to open dictionary file "model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict" for reading. No such file or directory.

So, where do I get this file now? Thank you.

Comment: All those files are available in pocketsphinx sources. En-us model is also available in pocketsphinx sources in model folder. cmusphinx-en-us-5.2.tar.gz  is not suitable for raspberry pi.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hope I will find that file. And for Raspberry Pi I should use the -ptm Version I guess?