# Python app listening for a keyword. (Like Cortana)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cortana

I'm trying to make a Python app, which behaves like Alexa, Cortana or Google's "Ok, Google".

I want it to constantly listen for a specific keyword. After it hears the keyword I want it to execute a function.
How can I do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @tverghis How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Speech Recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) This is a library that allows speech recognition including Google Cloud Speech API.

Relating to the second part of your question this seems relevant:

[How can i detect one word with speech recognition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596576/how-can-i-detect-one-word-with-speech-recognition-in-python)

Once you can listen for a word just call your function.

import speech_recognition as sr

```
# get audio from the microphone                                                                       
r = sr.Recognizer()                    
keywork = "hello"                                                                
with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
    print("Speak:")                                                                                   
    audio = r.listen(source)   

try:
    if  r.recognize_google(audio)) == keyword:
        myfunction()
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
```

This code was adapted from [this](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/) tutorial.

Comment: Oh, so I can just put the `listen()` function in a loop and that will work?

Comment: @J0K3R_12QQ  There is a little more I have added code to my post

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this in the morning (it's 12am where I live and I'm already sleeping).

Answer (score 3):

This will search for your keyword in the entire speech.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

keyWord = 'joker'

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Please start speaking..\n')
    while True: 
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)
            if keyWord.lower() in text.lower():
                print('Keyword detected in the speech.')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Please speak again.')
```

To improve your accuracy, you can even fetch all possible rhyming words and compare.

You can also do a character by character comparison to calculate the match percentage and set a minimum percentage threshold for the comparison success.

Comment: Can you help me, is that Python 3, please if it is not because so many errors.

Comment: Yes, it is python3

Comment: Like there are some errors, like it cannit actually listen to my voice, or is that because my mic is wrong.

Comment: @TroyD I believe that it's not a code issue. Please check if the mic is working and also if you're authorized to access the mic.

Comment: I can do zoom, and it works fine. Like classes, the teacher can hear.